# Swift 3 >> how to pass data to next view that have been received from HTTP POST Request

Tags: swift3, httprequest, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

please can you explain how to pass the json-data 
in "let result" to a new view e.g. a textfield?

Here is the related piece of code:

```
    // make http POST request
    let uploadTask = session.uploadTask(with: request as URLRequest, from: body?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!){
    (data, response, error) in

    (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode

    // URL Object to String
    let result = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    } 
    uploadTask.resume()
```

Comment: You can simply set `text` property of `UITextField` on main thread for that.  `let result = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8); 
DispatchQueue.main.async { self.textField.text = result }`

Comment: thanks so much; struggled since yesterday